# Matrix separating prime numbers and composite then sorts them

Tags: c, matrix

I have no ideas on how to do this.. i would appreciate it if someone helps,
In a matrix , where prime numbers come first and then composite , sorting is done by columns,

Here is an example.

Input:

```
25  3  7
11 15 32
16  9 19
```

Output:

```
 3 19 32
 7 25 16
11 15  9
```

Comment: Please provide your attempt at a solution

Comment: I don't understand the question, regardless of the example. How is the output related to the input? Please rephrase the question.

Comment: So you want to reorganise the matrix so that prime numbers are in sequence down the columns from left to right, and the rest are in ... random sequence?

Comment: @Codor The input is a regular matrix 3x3 with some random numbers , the output is where they are sorted by columns where the prime numbers come first as you can see then the composite. The output is just sorted. It is an example.

Comment: @WeatherVane As you can see the first two columns of the output are sorted and are prime numbers. The third is where the composite are . The prime always come first after that the composite. Do you understand me now? or should i use another method of explanation :D

Comment: It's not really a matrix is it? It's a linear array printed in three columns. BTW 25 and 15 in column 2 are not prime, and not sorted, so perhpas you "*should* use another method of explanation".

Comment: It is impossible to obtain the output by rearranging the columns of the input in your example.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is a matrix , just a random input output on how it should look like.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well the prime numbers end at 19 , since there are no prime , composite num are sorted.

Comment: How do you call `25 15 32 16 9` "sorted"?

Comment: @WeatherVane Look here , you make a function to check the matrix and sort it , starting check for prime numbers from first element im that number is prime it gets in first position and so on , until there are no more prime, the others must be composite its kind of like a bubble sort .

Comment: Well since you said "composite num are sorted" you need to make the bubble sort more sophisticated, but you started by saying you have no idea how to do this but now you mention bubble sort, I think you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = *(const int *)a;
    int y = *(const int *)b;
    int bx = isPrime(x);//0 or 1
    int by = isPrime(y);
    if(bx ^ by)
        return by - bx;
    else
        return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
}

int main(void){
    int i, j;
    int m[3][3] = {
        { 25,  3, 7},
        { 11, 15, 32},
        { 16,  9, 19}
    };
    qsort(&m[0][0], sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0][0]), sizeof(m[0][0]), cmp);
    for(i=0;i<2;++i){
        for(j=i+1;j<3;++j){
            int temp = m[i][j];
            m[i][j]  = m[j][i];
            m[j][i]  = temp;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;++i){
        for(j=0;j<3;++j)
            printf("%3d ", m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thaks alot Pixy! Seems like you are the most awesome guy on this page ;)

Comment: Since prime determination is hard, it might be better to partition on the 'is prime' property, then sort the two subsequences.  This works, though.

Comment: yes, It is better to be processed in advance because `isPrime` is likely to be called multiple for the same prime number.

Answer (score 2):

It may have nothing to do with sorting. Just find the next prime number and insert it in the current position:

```
25 3 7 11 15 32 16 9 19

3 25 7 11 15 32 16 9 19
3 7 25 11 15 32 16 9 19
3 7 11 25 15 32 16 9 19
3 7 11 19 25 15 32 16 9

3 19 32
7 25 16
11 15 9
```

We transform the matrix into the line by rows, but then, restore the matrix by columns. Anyway, the example is vague.